# Performance of changing values of STUArray in bulk

Tags: arrays, performance, sorting, haskell, graph

I am implementing a topological sort in Haskell with the requirement to be as efficient as possible. I have profiled my current solution and found out the the following method is taking 60% of total time (and 0 amount of additional space):

```
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.Word
import Data.Array.Base

zeroElementsAfterDecrement' :: (MArray a e m, Num e, Eq e) => a Int e -> [Int] -> m [Int]
zeroElementsAfterDecrement' arr is = foldr k (return []) is
  where k i a = do xs <- a
                   decremented <- liftM (subtract 1) (unsafeRead arr i)
                   unsafeWrite arr i decremented
                   if decremented == 0 then return (i:xs) else return xs

largenum :: Int
largenum = 10000000
test = runST $ do arr <- newArray (1, largenum) 100 :: ST s (STUArray s Int Word32)
                  zeroElementsAfterDecrement' arr [1..largenum]


main = (putStrLn . show) test
```

The function takes an array (I use unboxed mutable arrays) and a list of indexes, decrements elements by these indexes and returns indexes of elements that became zero during this operation. Right now this is more than 10 times slower than the optimized C++ code but still pretty good compared to Python (or maybe I don't know Python way to optimize this). I understand there is an overhead from executing a monadic code, but maybe there are still ways to optimize I am not aware of?

**Edit:**

GHC: -O -fllvm: 0.54s
GHC (with unsafeWrite/unsafeRead and Word32): 0.34s
g++: 0.24s
g++ -O2: 0.05s
python3: 2.66s

Also when I change foldr to foldl' it starts allocating some memory and is 4 times slower as a result, why is that?

Here is a C++ version I compared it to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#define LARGENUM 10000000

int main()
{
    vector <int> arr; 
    for (int i = 0; i < LARGENUM; i++) {
        arr.push_back(100);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        arr[i]--;
        if (arr[i] == 0)
            cout << i << endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

And a Python version:

```
arr = [100] * 10000000

for x in range (0, 10000000 - 1):
    arr[x] = arr[x] - 1
    if arr[x] == 0:
        print x
```

Comment: Do you also return indices of zero elements in C in a linked list?

Comment: Even better — I pushed them to `priority_queue<int>` one by one.

Comment: OK. What's the usual size of the input arrays and what's the size of the output list? (I'm trying to do some benchmarking).

Comment: To be honest, I didn't do a benchmarking of the reduction of this function separately, only in context. But profiling data shows the following: `zeroElementsAfterDecrement'` ran 10000 times, spent 0 time and 0 space. `zeroElementsAfterDecrement'.k` ran 9499500 times total, spent 60% of time 0 space.

Comment: Maybe it does not matter, but I'd try specializing the above to the exact monad and the exact array type, either manually or via `{-# SPECIALIZE #-}`. Check the Core to see if GHC is not already doing this for you.

Comment: I have manually specified the signature but it didn't make any difference. Looking at the Core I don't see any "Spec" expressions, but it looks like it just specialized it and inlined right in place. I have also tried using Word32 and unsafe read/write and that helped to reduce the time almost by half.